# Is there a .NET API to get Facebook friend's info (email, phone, birthday etc.)

Tags: .net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

All i see is birthday/email at at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Is there a way to get phone number also ?

and which is the best Facebook C# SDK for this purpose.

I checked out http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com . Is it the best option ?

*EDIT:*

I now see that probably there is no direct way to get personal info of friends.
What is the whole thing about  getting express permissions to get this info ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to get data on your friends is http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com "Get-FBFriends -Fields birthday,email" (plus whatever other fields you want from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/). This won't help with phone number, which simply isn't exposed to Facebook applications.

Comment: So, there is no way to get phone numbers without explicit user (friend) permission ?

Comment: I don't know of any way to get phone numbers from the Facebook Graph API, with or without explicit permissions. It simply isn't exposed, presumably for privacy reasons.

Comment: it doesn't appear possible to get email for friends either... only your own email address.  Jon - is this something you've gotten to work?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ seems to indicate that there is no permission which would grant access to friends' email addresses.